# Is counter example a valid form of counterexample?

Tags: orthography, mathematics

In student writing about math, I see the term "counter example" instead of "counterexample" too often. Does anyone have good ideas about why people think "counterexample" is two words?  When I see the term "counter example" I think of something you'd find in a home furnishings store.

I don't see people misspell the terms like counterpart or counterintuitive by making them two words.

Comment: If a *counter example* is an example that counters an example that supports the thesis, it’s a *counterexample* of the thesis. But the counter example might be countering a counterexample, in which case that counter example would be confirming the thesis.

Comment: @Lawrence I am not sure what point you are trying to make, but “counter example” is a completely nonstandard term in math, unlike counterexample.

Comment: My comment was about the English terms, which I assumed was relevant since you posted your question on [english.se]. If you're talking about purely mathematical terminology, have a look at [math.se].

Comment: "Counter" is a perfectly valid adjective and therefore it's reasonable to place it before the noun "example". A "counterexample" is something that disproves a general statement or hypothesis/theory. But a "counter example" is an example that in MW's definition is "marked by or tending toward or in an opposite direction or effect" without necessarily disproving anything. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counter

Comment: Google gives lots of examples of "counter part", so it's clearly a mistake people make; there are slightly fewer for "counter intuitive" although there is a record label with that name. Since "counterintuitive" is an adjective unlike counterpart/counterexample, it's maybe less likely people will write it as two separate words: they'll hyphenate it, which we see happening.